# Authenticate user with Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

Assume we have endpoint like this `/users/{userId}/messages/{messageId}` and which is exposed via `@DeleteMapping` (as endpoint suggest's, it delete's message with specified ID, for specified user). 
`Message` can be deleted in two cases: you are moderator, or you are owner of the message. The first part is quiet easy, you can add in `Security configuration` that you need `ROLE_MODERATOR` to use this endoint. But there is second case, when you can delete message if you are owner. How to implement it properly? If you add `ROLE_MODERATOR` in `Security configuration` you are disabling enpoint for non moderator users (including some owners of message). 
Assume we have service called `AuthenticatedUserHolder` with method `getLoggedUserID()` which will return `userID` (session, JWT or sth). Is there any way to combine `ROLE_MODERATOR` or message owner?

Second question: Assume we have endpoint `/users/{id}/addresses` with `@PutMapping` and you can change address only if `loggedUserID == id`. How to extract logic from `service/facade` that will return `401/403` if `loggedUserID != id`?

Edit: Method code:

```
SecurityContext authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    UserPrincipal loggedUser = (UserPrincipal) authentication.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    return loggedUser.getUser().getPersonId();
```

UserPrincipal has extra field `personId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @PreAuthorize annotation with a custom method
[Examples](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security)

Controller

```
@PreAuthorize("@beanName.beanMethodName(#controllerParamName)")
@GetMapping("/{controllerParamName}")
fun getMethod(@PathVariable("controllerParamName") param: Long) {
    //whenever
}
```

Validation Bean

```
@Service
class BeanName {
   fun beanMethodName(param: Long): Boolean {
      return false
   }
}
```

Comment: Everything looked fine, but I am getting error: `Attempted to call method loggedUserId() on null context object` when i am trying to get `loggedUserId` from `Authentication` via service. It looks like `Authentication` isn't built before `@PreAuthorize` annotation has beed processed. I've put method code in question. 
Edit: Nah, it looks like `Spring Context` wasn't build at all. Like `@PreAuthorize` is called before whole context is build. How can i use components in `@PreAuthorize`?